# Predicate not work as expected in Prolog (SICStus)

Tags: prolog, sicstus-prolog

I have a problem with prolog predicate.

I have one board and i want to check when one player dont have pieces with values between 1 and 10 called mobile pieces. The code are showed above:

```
test_board([
      [piece('   ',12,blk),piece('R2 ',2,red),piece('RB ',11,red),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk)],
      [piece('   ',12,blk),piece('RB ',11,red),piece('RF ',0,red),piece('RB ',11,red),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('RB ',11,red),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk)],
      [piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('RB ',11,red),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk)],
      [piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk)],
      [piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk)],
      [piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('X  ',13,for),piece('   ',12,blk),piece('   ',12,blk)],
      [piece('B6 ', 6,blue),piece('B4 ', 4,blue),piece('B5 ', 5,blue),piece('B10',10,blue),piece('B7 ', 7,blue),piece('B4 ', 4,blue),piece('B8 ', 8,blue),piece('B9 ', 9,blue),piece('B5 ', 5,blue),piece('B4 ', 4,blue)],
      [piece('B7 ', 7,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('B5 ', 5,blue),piece('BB ',11,blue),piece('B3 ', 3,blue),piece('B6 ', 6,blue),piece('B3 ', 3,blue),piece('B1 ', 1,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('B3 ', 3,blue)],
      [piece('B3 ', 3,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('BB ',11,blue),piece('B3 ', 3,blue),piece('BB ',11,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('BB ',11,blue),piece('B6 ', 6,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('B7 ', 7,blue)],
      [piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('B6 ', 6,blue),piece('B5 ', 5,blue),piece('B4 ', 4,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue),piece('BB ',11,blue),piece('BF ',0,blue),piece('BB ',11,blue),piece('B8 ', 8,blue),piece('B2 ', 2,blue)]]
).

check_mobile_pieces([],_):-
  fail.

check_mobile_pieces([BoardHead|BoardTail],Opponent):-
  check_mobile_pieces_line(BoardHead,Opponent);
  check_mobile_pieces(BoardTail,Opponent).

check_mobile_pieces_line([],_):-
  fail.

check_mobile_pieces_line([LineHead|LineTail],Opponent):-
  piece(_,PieceValue,Opponent)=LineHead,
  ((PieceValue > 0, PieceValue<11) -> true
                                   ;check_mobile_pieces_line(LineTail,Opponent)).
```

In this example the result should be "yes" but is "no"..Why? Anyone can get the error in code?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should say what query you issue, isn't apparent to me. Indeed much of the Prolog behaviour is controlled with instantiation of variables, and without knowing what's `Opponent` binding it's hard to answer.

Anyway, I think you will get `false` because `Opponent` keep changing for each element in a line, then `piece(_,PieceValue,Opponent)=LineHead,` will make check_mobile_pieces_line/2 will fail before performing the test you are interested in.

**edit** the simplest way to search in a list is using member/2. Then to see if a Player has movable pieces:

```
has_movable(Player) :-
  test_board(Board),
  member(Row, Board),                    % peek a row
  member(piece(_, Value, Player), Row),  % peek a Player'piece
  Value > 0, Value < 11.
```

To say that a Player has no movables:

```
....
\+ has_movable(Player),
....
```

Comment: The Opponent is the Player (red or blue) that i want to check if has pieces with value >0 and <11, if he has then predicate is true, if he hasnt then predicate is false...This is what i want, but not work.